# Ranking a partial field match to a query above a complete match on a different field

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm implementing a name search where the possible fields are `first_name`, `middle_initial`, and `last_name`. Queries are usually last name first, e.g. "Smith, A" when looking for "Smith, Ashley" instead of "A Smith".

My results are scoring undesirably (**Angela and Alex should be above Robert and Ted**):

- "Smith, Roger A"
- "Smith, Ted A"
- "Smith, Angela D"
- "Smith, Alex N"

I've tried a lot of things both on the indexing and querying, and I have to include a fair amount of fuzziness (spelling and phonetic). The `cross_match` query + some fuzziness via an n-gram analyzer has met most of my needs except for this. Edit: the list above is ordered by `_score`, so I can't sort by other things.

Querying example, where I was trying to see if indexing the first & middle name together made a difference:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "smith, a",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "first_name_middle_initial^5",
              "last_name^10"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "smith, a",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "first_name_middle_initial.phonetic^2",
              "last_name.phonetic^5"
            ]
          }
        },
       {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "smith, a",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "first_name_middle_initial.analyzed^2",
              "last_name.analyzed^10"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "last_name.word_start": {
                    "query": "smith, a",
                    "boost": 10,
                    "operator": "and",
                    "analyzer": "searchkick_word_search"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "last_name.word_start": {
                    "query": "smith, a",
                    "boost": 5,
                    "operator": "and",
                    "analyzer": "searchkick_word_search",
                    "fuzziness": 1,
                    "prefix_length": 0,
                    "max_expansions": 3,
                    "fuzzy_transpositions": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "first_name_middle_initial.word_start": {
                    "query": "smith, a",
                    "boost": 10,
                    "operator": "and",
                    "analyzer": "searchkick_word_search"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

I've also fiddled with the boost, trying to drown out whatever is matching on the middle initial, and even not including the middle initial in my query or the fields I'm referencing in the query (e.g. `first_name` only) for this at all. I can't ignore middle initial entirely in case it's the differentiating field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one of my problems may have been an out of date index. Otherwise the keys seemed to be using an ngram analyzer as one of my `cross_fields` matches and making sure the `middle_initial` was considered completely independently (sort of as a tiebreaker). Putting it in a `bool` subquery was intentional -- I don't want it and the other subqueries in that clause to be considered with the same weight as the `cross_fields` matches, as per [this section of the elasticsearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html#prioritising-clauses).

Here's what ultimately solved my problem:

**Index mapping:**

```
{
  <snip>
      "first_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "phonetic": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "word_start": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "searchkick_word_start_index" // includes "lowercase", "asciifolding", "searchkick_edge_ngram" (ngram from the start of the word)
          }
        }
      },
      <snip>
      "last_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "phonetic": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
          },
          "word_start": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "searchkick_word_start_index"
          }
        }
      },
      "middle_initial": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "analyzed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "searchkick_index" // includes lowercase, asciifolding, shingles, stemmer
          }
        },
        "ignore_above": 30000
      },
      <snip>
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "smith, s",
              "type": "cross_fields",
              "fields": [
                "first_name^2",
                "last_name^3"
              ],
              "tie_breaker": 0.3
            }
          },
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "smith, s",
              "type": "cross_fields",
              "fields": [
                "first_name.phonetic",
                "last_name.phonetic"
              ],
              "tie_breaker": 0.3
            }
          },
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "smith, s",
              "type": "cross_fields",
              "fields": [
                "first_name.word_start",
                "last_name.word_start^2"
              ],
              "tie_breaker": 0.3
            }
          }
        ],
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
            <snip subquery for another field>
              {
                "match": {
                  "middle_initial.analyzed": {
                    "query": "s",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```